# Delete elements from PHP array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays. And another array of arrays. If there is an array with a value common I want it to be delted from the first array: Here is my code

```
function availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate) {
        $tablesReturn = array();

        foreach($tables as $table) {
          foreach($tablesWithDate as $twd) {
             if($table['table_no'] == $twd['number']){
                  echo "true";
             } else {
               echo "false";
             }
          }
        }
        return $tablesReturn;
      }
```

With this the output is false for every iteration except 2 that return true. Which is correct, but id like to delete them from the first array. I have tried:

```
function availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate) {
        $tablesReturn = array();

        foreach($tables as $table) {
          foreach($tablesWithDate as $twd) {
             if($table['table_no'] == $twd['number']){
                  unset($table);
             } else {
               echo "false";
             }
          }
        }
        return $tablesReturn;
      }
```

But does not work. It says undefined variable table. I have also tried `unset($tables[$table])`

$TablesWithDate:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [number] => 150
            [capacity] => 4
            [booking_code] => qhJEHcWnzty062DD
            [reservation_date] => 2020-07-09 01:00:00
            [start_time] => 12:30:00.000000
            [end_time] => 14:15:00.000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [number] => 150
            [capacity] => 4
            [booking_code] => ym9dP1aZtFstP3WM
            [reservation_date] => 2020-07-22 01:00:00
            [start_time] => 20:00:00.000000
            [end_time] => 21:45:00.000000
        )
)
```

tables:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 159
            [table_no] => 150
            [capacity] => 6
            [shape] => large_rectangle
            [joinable] => 1
            [area] => 1
            [baby_friendly] => 1
            [premise_code] => LJJIDHhRN2ho1e3h
            [area_name] => Ferkin
            [premise_name] => An Poitin Stil
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 160
            [table_no] => 150
            [capacity] => 4
            [shape] => small_rectangle
            [joinable] => 1
            [area] => 1
            [baby_friendly] => 1
            [premise_code] => LJJIDHhRN2ho1e3h
            [area_name] => Ferkin
            [premise_name] => An Poitin Stil
        )
)
```

Comment: Please create a proper [mre], including sample data in the appropriate format, so that we can reproduce what you are talking about here.

Comment: Edited with data for both arrays

Comment: Please use `var_export`, that will generate _code_ we can use directly.

Comment: No you have the information you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index($key in code) of the tables array and unset using `unset($tables[$key]`.

```
function availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate) {
        $tablesReturn = array();

        foreach($tables as $key => $table) {
          foreach($tablesWithDate as $twd) {
             if($table['table_no'] == $twd['number']){
               unset($tables[$key]);
             } else {
               echo "false";
             }
          }
        }
        return $tables;
      }
```

Comment: That just returns me a blank array :(

Comment: You need to return `$table` in the last line.

Comment: That is because in the original code that you had shared, the array `$tablesReturn` is empty, and it's not being modified. The code was to update the `$tables` array.

Comment: Yeah @jh1711 is right, thanks. I just copied what you wrote in the post.